# Use ProgressRing In MVVM WinUI 3

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, winui-3

I have a ProgressRing in my xaml that on processing my command, it will rotate:

```
<ProgressRing Name="progressRing" IsActive="{Binding ProgressActive}" />
```

I have a bool Property as the name in the binding shows. at the first line of my command, I enable (True) this value and wanted to see the progress ring. I tested it on debug and the value is changing, but nothing on the display. I used Mode OneWay and TwoWay.

If I set a default value for my binding property, It will work if I run, but nothing if application is running and wanted to change it with ViewModel and Command.

Like this:

```
public bool ProgressActive { get; set; } = true;
```

Thanks

Comment: The object where you define this property must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) and you must raise a change event, ie: `PropertertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProgressActive"));` when the value changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the UI that the property has changed by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I always use the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package for this.

The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package comes with source generators that generate `INotifyPropertyChanged` related code for you.

- [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject?source=recommendations#how-it-works)
- [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty#how-it-works)

```cs
// This class needs to be "partial" for the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // This will create an UI interactive "ProgressActive" property for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _progressActive;
}
```

Comment: I didn't really get '[ObservableProperty]'. I put it but nothing special happened. If I implement INotifyPropertyChanged, It will work and thanks. but is your answer simpler for propertychange if user has CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package?

Comment: The Attribute '[ObservableProperty]' Needs SetProperty() Method to work as it should. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You don't need SetProperty. Just make sure you installed the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package to your project. The **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm**'s source generator will generate that code for you. I updated my answer.

Comment: OWWWW. Now I understand What is Happening, lol. Thank you. I had my Property and It was making mess with '[ObservableProperty]'. I removed it and just kept my field and everything works as it should be. Really ez. nice. Thank you so much.